# Salesforce REST Api missing fields with PHP

Tags: php, api, salesforce

I'm using the **Salesforce REST API** and found it very hard to find decent documentation. 
I can successfully log in with OAuth and i can push new accounts to Salesforce.
I use the instance url to make the API calls and i send the following fields to create an account object:

```
Name
Rating
Description
```

The problem is that I created a free trial (which sits on na9.salesforce.com) and everything worked fine.

I created a second free trial to check if everything works with another account, but the rating field is not available... I get the following message from Salesforce:

```
"[{"message":"No such column 'rating' on sobject of Account"}]"
```

Why is that?

Also, is it possible to add notes to a created account using POST? And is it possible to create Leads instead of Accounts using the API?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can your retrieve the Account if you look only for the Name?

Answer (score 0):

A feature called field level security (FLS) can mean that even standard fields are not accessible, check the FLS settings on account in your second org.

Docs for the REST API are on the [developer force site](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest250/index.htm)